# How do I access a router's web interface through another router?

Tags: networking, routing

My connection goes like:

ISP -> Modem -> Router A -> Router B -> Computers

The reason why I have two routers is that my modem and my computers are in different rooms and I use router B to bridge the distance between them. Router B is set up as a LAN switch and wireless access point, while router A is set up as a pure gateway.

I'd like to be able to access router A's web interface through router B. Is that possible? Keep in mind that they are in different subnets. (router A: 192.168.9.1; router B: 192.168.0.1) Both routers support port forwarding and routing tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as Router B has a route for Router A (and it presumably does, since traffic to the internet must go through it), simply pointing a browser at 192.168.9.1 (with, as yosh m points out, a port specified if it's not the usual 80) from one of the computers on the network should provide access to Router A's web interface.

Comment: Of course, you may need to add a port number to that, e.g., 192.168.9.1:88 or 192.168.9.1:8080, etc., depending on what you've defined on Router A. To verify your Router A settings, temporarily attach a computer directly to it using a wire.

Comment: A good point that.  Most default to 80 as the web-interface, at least internally, but I'll edit it in.

Comment: That worked. I can't believe I hadn't tried it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use router B as a repeater. Then you stay on the same network. You can install DD-WRT on one of the routers, and then configure that router as a repeater bridge. Although it's a bit of work to get this working, it's probably a lot easier when it works.

See http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge